# Ember .transitionToRoute and currentModel issue

Tags: javascript, ember.js, javascript-framework

My route is defined:

```
this.resource("visitor", {path: ":id"});
```

When I visit the page via the URL `/12345`, the value of `this.currentModel` is

```
{id: "12345"}
```

but when I `this.transitionToRoute("visitor", "12345")` from another (parent) controller, the value of `this.currentModel` is

```
"12345"
```

I also get this exception:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Path '12345' must be global if no obj is given.
```

Any ideas what's going on?

More code:

```
App.VisitorRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return {id: params.id};
  },
  setupController: function() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explain to the router how to translate your model into a URL, for that you need to override `serialize`.

```
App.VisitorRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return {id: params.id};
  },
  serialize: function(model) {
    return model;  
  }
});
```

After that pass the model with the transition:

```
this.transitionToRoute('visitor' , { id: 12345 });
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call this.transitionToRoute() you need to pass in the route and the model as arguments, so instead of this.transitionToRoute("visitor", "12345"), rather use this.transitionToRoute("visitor", vistorModel)